# Populating multiple dropdowns from single source and changing data dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a table named employee.  I am fetching data from this table into 5 drop-downs with fields EmpNo, Unit, Location, Onsite/Offshore etc.,  When i am selecting a value in any of the drop-downs the values in all the drop-downs have to change.  Can anyone pls help me how can i acheive this??

Comment: WinForms? ASP.NET? WPF?

Answer (score 0):

**Server side solution**

There is a `SelectedIndexChanged` event for the dropdown control. In that event, you need to reset all other dropdowns or reload some other data.

**Client side solution (with jQuery)**

Listen to the `change` event of the first dropdown and clear the other dropdown content in that event.

```
$(function(){
  $("#IDofFirstDropDown").change(function(e){
    $("#IDofSecond").html("");
  });
});
```

Comment: I have used the selectedIndexchanged event and reloaded the data but the problem is i need to show the value selected in dropdowns where a value is selected and in the remaining dropdowns i need to show ALL.

Comment: What is stopping you from doing so ?

Comment: for showing ALL i need to use AppendDataBoundItems. but before reloading i am clearing the data in the dropdown, am losing my selected index. So i wasn't able to do so

Comment: `CheckQuery()
{
if (ddlEmpNo.SelectedValue != "" && ddlEmpNo.SelectedValue != "ALL")
    Query = Query + " and Emp_No = " + ddlEmpNo.SelectedValue;
if (ddlEmpName.SelectedValue != "" && ddlEmpName.SelectedValue != "ALL")
    Query = Query + " and Emp_Name = '" + ddlEmpName.SelectedValue + "'";
if (ddlEmail_ID.SelectedValue != "" && ddlEmail_ID.SelectedValue != "ALL")
    Query = Query + " and Emp_mailID = '" + ddlEmail_ID.SelectedValue + "'";
}

Comment: protected void SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  DataTable dtEmpList = checkQuery();
  ddlEmpNo.DataSource = dtEmpList;
  ddlEmpName.DataSource = dtEmpList;
  ddlEmail_ID.DataSource = dtEmpList;
  ddlEmpNo.DataBind();
  ddlEmpName.DataBind();
  ddlEmail_ID.DataBind();
} `

Comment: Got the solution finally!!